# iPhone Simulator 6.0 in Xcode 4.5.2 and OS X 10.8.2 has stopped working, can I reinstall it?

Tags: iphone, xcode, simulator

I have read many threads from this forum but never asked any questions. I ran into this problem and I need some help please. I'm using Xcode 4.5.2 on my OS X 10.8.2. Until today everything worked fine, but today my iPhone 6.0 Simulator has stopped working. I have a simple iPhone app I made and when I try to run it now into my simulator I get an error and it crushes. In fact the simulator doesn't start at all, I just get this error message which gets sent to Apple. I'll post the error message below. I'm more of a Windows guy quite new to Mac and wondering if there is a way to reinstall the simulator or any other advice will be appreciated. Thanks!
Here is the crush report:

```
Process:         iPhone Simulator [9681]
Path:            /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator
Identifier:      com.apple.iphonesimulator
Version:         6.0 (358.4)
Build Info:      Indigo-358004000000000~83
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [237]
User ID:         501

Date/Time:       2012-11-09 00:01:31.039 +1100
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.2 (12C60)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          5921 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           40577
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  18 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   9
Anonymous UUID:                      XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000210

VM Regions Near 0x210:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010ab1b000-000000010ab46000 [  172K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Applications/iPhone Simulator.app/Contents/MacOS/iPhone Simulator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, problem solved, it turned out that I have some bad blocks on my HDD so I had to clone my HDD with the CCC (cloner) onto another HDD and everything works nice and smooth. I used TechTool app to check my system but even this app crashed during check which made me think it'm my HDD. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

best thing to do is reinstall Xcode completely to be safe. It could be the simulator, or even a process run by xcode to launch it.

also check that your RAM is ok by running an apple hardware test. This can sometimes be related to this issue

your project wont be affected at all so there are no worries there.

also try using [This](http://www.codza.com/how-to-debug-exc_bad_access-on-iphone) to get yourself started